# No module found when importing win32api

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was learning Python recently and I encountered one question. I tried to install pywin32 via pip pypiwin32 or the binary. And the installation showed successful for both case. The strange thing is when I directly typed:`import win32api`in the CMD, it worked fine. But when I wrote it in a python.py and drag the file in the CMD, the error message: "No module named win32api" rose. Anything I can do solve this problem? I am running python 3.6.2 in windows 7.

Please forgive me for my poor English.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Is only Python 3 installed in your computer or do you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: Hi, @Irfanuddin, my code is the same as the line that I type in the CMD, which it is ‘import win32api’. I have two version installed in my computer.  Python 3.6.2 and 2.7. My cmd path is set as the Python 3.6.2 directory. And I have also checked the win32 folder is inside the site-package folder under Python 3.6.2. When I install from binary, I downloaded the amd 64 for Python 3.6 version. Although my cpu is intel, the Python version shown on the cmd is amd 64 Python 3.6.2. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Can you try installing using `pip3`?